# How to fired the records by multiples of 3

Tags: trigger, email

i am new in salesforce, my question is how to send email only the records counting by 3

for ex: assume 20 records in case object. we send only email to record 3, record 6, record 9, record 12, record 15 and record 18 only

please help me!

Thanks in advance!

Comment: My experience tells me that you should always use workflows/process builders to send emails. So, i suggest you configure a workflow based on an autonumber field and check as a criteria of the workflow for that number to be multiples of 3 and then send an email alert.

Answer (score 0):

I believe first you have to find how are you sequencing your records. I mean when you query these 20 records, the list sequence is indeterminate. You will have to add a order by clause.

Then you can loop over these records in `for i` loop and check.

```
List<Case> cases = [Select Id, email from Case Order by CreatedDate];

for(integer i = 0; i < cases.size(); i++){
     if((i+1)%3 == 0 ){
           //Add it to a list to send email.
     }
}
```

Instead of that I think a better approach would be to create a field on case to determine for which records to send an email.

Answer (score 0):

**More Efficiently you can use this**

```
 integer cases = [Select  count() from Case WHERE CreatedDate = Today];
    system.debug(cases);
    for(integer i = 1; i <= cases; i++){
         if(math.mod(i, 3) == 0 ){
             system.debug('send Email');
         }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create autoNumber field and then write Workflow email alert that will check if the field value
divided by 3 then send email alert